# Display information from decoded JSON in a UILabel (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, json, swift, decode

I am trying to display information taken from JSON. I've used .decode to get it. Now I want to put its text onto a simple label on my storyboard. At the bottom under ".resume()" is my attempt and it isn't working. I can't seem to figure this out.

---

```
import UIKit


struct WebsiteDescription: Decodable {
    var name : String
    var description : String
    var courses : [Course]

}


struct Course: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let link: String
    let imageUrl: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var displayLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let jsonUrlString = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/jsondecodable/website_description"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else {return}

            do {
                let websiteDescription = try JSONDecoder().decode(WebsiteDescription.self, from: data)
                print(websiteDescription.name, websiteDescription.description, websiteDescription.courses)
                //let courses = try JSONDecoder().decode([Course].self, from: data)
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json", jsonErr)
            }

        }.resume()

        let displayLabel.text = websiteDescription.name

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your label from within the do method. Also you should do it from the main thread so that the UI can be updated. I have updated the code below.

```
import UIKit

struct WebsiteDescription: Decodable { 
    var name : String 
    var description : String 
    var courses : [Course]
}

struct Course: Decodable { 
    let id: Int 
    let name: String 
    let link: String 
    let imageUrl: String 
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var displayLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        let jsonUrlString = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/jsondecodable/website_description"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else {return}

        do {
            let websiteDescription = try JSONDecoder().decode(WebsiteDescription.self, from: data)
            print(websiteDescription.name, websiteDescription.description, websiteDescription.courses)
            //let courses = try JSONDecoder().decode([Course].self, from: data)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.displayLabel.text = websiteDescription.name
            }

         } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json", jsonErr)
        }

    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: This is a lifesaver. Thank you @Cedan!

Comment: @Westopher: Glad that this answer works for you. Please upvote and accept the answer to acknowledge it.

Comment: @Westopher You are welcome. Please upvote and accept this as the answer. Thanks.